# Can I run my Sheevaplug Arch Linux's usb key in a Virtual Machine on my computer?

Tags: virtualization, arch-linux

It's pretty much all in the title.. I've bought a pogoplug, installed Arch Linux on it on a USB key. I would like to take that USB key and run the enclosed ARM OS in a virtual machine on my Mac. Anything possible or the x86 -> ARM stuff is impossible or impractical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, QEMU can do it, here's a similar project using it http://www.aurel32.net/info/debian_arm_qemu.php

Note this is Emulation and not Virtualization as the other comment mentions.

Answer (score 0):

You would need an ARM emulator, and it doesn't appear that there is one that can directly run images build for sheevaplug[1].  Virtualization requires the guest OS be able to run using the same instruction set as the host (or, in the case of x86 on x86_64, a subset of the same instruction set).

[1]. http://plugcomputer.org/plugforum/index.php?topic=113.0